# JavaScript Function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to store TextBox value in HidenField and i am calling javascript function on button click function is calling getting message Hi but... textBox getting null....I am using asp.net TextBox and also i have tried with HTML textBox also but same scenario happing in both the case...Actually HTML code using in Ajax Tab Container may be this problem ...
How to solve such type of problem

```
function f11() {
    alert("Hi")
    alert("hi..." + document.getElementById("txthtmltextbox").value)
    document.getElementById("txtuncheaderHF").value = document.getElementById("txthtmltextbox").value;
    document.getElementById("txtrootFolderHF").value = document.getElementById("txthtmltextboxroot").value
}
```

This is my HTML code

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlhfconfig" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%">
    <table bordercolor="gainsboro" bgcolor="white" style="border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-width: 1px; border-left-style: solid;
        border-right-width: 1px; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-color: #8C8B83;
        border-top-color: #8C8B83; border-left-color: #8C8B83; border-right-color: #8C8B83;"
        id="TABLE2" language="javascript">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" height="20" class="topnav" style="font-size: 10px;
                    font-family: verdana">
                    <font style="color: #000000"><strong>
                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal4" runat='server' Text='HF Configuration'></asp:Literal>&#160;&#160;</strong></font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbluncheader" runat="server" Text='HotFolder UNCHeader'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>                                                                                                                                                                  
                    <input type="text" id="txthtmltextbox" name="txthtmltextbox" onblur="f1()" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Style="z-index: 102;" Width="250px" />

                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvuncheader" runat="server"
                            ErrorMessage="UNCHeader is required." ControlToValidate="txthtmltextbox" Display="None"
                            ValidationGroup="save"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblrootfolder" runat="server" Text='Hot RootFolder'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>

                <input type="text" id="txthtmltextboxroot" name="txthtmltextboxroot" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Style="z-index: 102;" Width="250px" />

                   <%-- <asp:TextBox ID="txtrootfolder" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>--%><asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                        ID="rfvUNH" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RootFolder is required." ControlToValidate="txthtmltextboxroot"
                        Display="None" ValidationGroup="save"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnsave" OnClientClick ="f1()"   runat="server" Text='Save' Width="55px" BackColor="#E5E5E5"
                                    ForeColor="Black" ValidationGroup="save" />


                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btncancel" runat="server" Text='Cancel' Width="55px" BackColor="#E5E5E5"
                                    ForeColor="Black" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="True"
                                    ShowSummary="False" ValidationGroup="save" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: it happens due to post back....post back causes the page to refresh

Comment: try adding a return false in your f11 function at the end

Comment: no change after adding return false

Answer (score 2):

Hope you aware of JQuery and using JQuery, you will easily get inner control of panel. Because when your page is render on browser. Html code is something different then .NET(ASPX page).

You will get/set panel inner control value using below statement.

```
$("#<%=pnlhfconfig.ClientID %> input[id='<%= txtuncheaderHF.ClientID %>']").val($("#<%=pnlhfconfig.ClientID %> input[id='<%= txthtmltextbox.ClientID %>']").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `txthtmltextbox` please check on console what is the actual ID of control while generating html.

Or use as

```
 document.getElementById("<%= txthtmltextbox.ClientID%>").value
```

Comment: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)...Getting Error in Mozilla 26.0

Comment: I was miss `"` please try now

Comment: same Error after adding Quoation